# How do I fix this Django Import Error?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This feels like one of those questions nobody will be able to answer but I'll ask it anyway.  I have a Django 1.6 project that is raising an import error when I try to access my site's home page via the Django development server:

```
ImportError at /
No module named photo
```

The error is occurring at this line at the top of one of my views:

```
# apps/photos/views.py
from classes.photo import Photo
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'apps.admin',
 'apps.account',
 'apps.home',
 'apps.members',
 'apps.messages',
 'apps.payment',
 'apps.photos',
 'apps.signin',
 'apps.profile',
 'scripts',
 'apps.try',
 'favicon',
 'django_nose',
 'django_extensions')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/www/yearbook/conf/urls.py" in <module>
  16.     url(r'^photos/',             include('apps.photos.urls')),
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/Users/me/venv/yearbook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "/www/yearbook/apps/photos/urls.py" in <module>
  5. from apps.photos.views import ack_photos_uploaded
File "/www/yearbook/apps/photos/views.py" in <module>
  11. from classes.photo import Photo

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named photo
```

Normally this type of problem is easy to solve but this one has me baffled.  I have a number of apps in my "yearbook" project including the photos app in question:

```
yearbook (Django project)
├── admin
├── apps (My various apps... see below)
├── bin
├── classes  (photo.py in here)
├── conf (my settings.py and config files)
├── manage.py
├── scripts
├── static
└── templates

apps
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── account
├── home
├── members
├── messages
├── photos  (<- problem occurs here)
├── profile
└── signin
```

classes/photo.py is Python module that contains a Photo class and various instance, static, and class methods needed to manipulate photos.  I use a class instead of a model because I don't need to store photo-related information in my database.

```
# classes/photo.py
class Photo:
    # instance variables and various methods here
    pass
```

What's strange about this error is that I can add "from classes.photo import Photo" to any of my other apps' views and I don't get this error.  In fact, my "admin" and "profile" apps import and make extensive use of the photo module's Photo class.  It only happens when I add it to my photos view.py file.  It feels like some sort of name collision but I don't see how that could be since the path for my class module is /www/yearbook/classes/photo.py but the view that tries to import it is in /www/yearbook/apps/photos/views.py.  Both the classes and apps/photos directories have empty `__init__.py` files in them.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?  This is particularly frustrating because it means my photo management app isn't able to manipulate photos using a photo class that I built to support managing photos.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably a circular dependency issue. Does classes.photo import photos.views?

Comment: That's a good thought but, no, classes.photo does not import apps.photos.views.

Comment: from yearbook.classes.photo import Photo?

Comment: @AjayGupta Yes, I tried that too but it didn't fix it.

Comment: then its a circular import problem i think

Comment: I'm not sure sure this is a circular import problem.  I commented everything out of my photos view except for some Python and Django library imports at the top and the "from classes import photo" statement in question.  I then added back the first main view method "manage_photos" which only does a render_to_response of the main photos page.  After doing this, I got the same ImportError.  At this point, I don't think there was enough code in the view to cause any type of circular import error.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what the problem was.  I also happened to have a classes.py file in my yearbook/apps/photos directory.  Django seems to have been confusing it with my years/classes directory when I tried to import Photo from my classes.photo module from within apps/photos/views.py.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add a `__init__.py` to your folder **classes**. This way python knows it's part of your project.

Comment: You must not have read my question all the way through because I said I had done that.